# Can't add item to PasswordCredential.Properties field (C# uwp)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

When I try to call the `Add` method of `PasswordCredential.Properties`, the method raises an `ArgumentException`.

```
PasswordCredential p = new PasswordCredential(resource, userName, password);
p.Properties.Add(stringProperty, stringValue);
```

How is possible to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227061#properties) it is Read-only and that is why the exception is raised. It is used internal and should never be used in your code.

What are you trying to add?

Comment: I wish to add some property linked to a Password credential, like a website where the password credential is valid, but to store them in the PasswordVault service.

Comment: It seems like what you are trying to do is not possible. I guess you have to handle that by yourself, may saving it it a dictionary with a key/value where the key is the UserName.